# Yii2: custom setter method/data transformation doesn't work on ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-model

I'm trying to do data transformation on an attribute by using the setter method `setUsr_firstname` for an attribute that is named `usr_firstname`.

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface {

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['usr_firstname', 'usr_lastname', ... ], 'required'],
            ...
        ];
    }

    ...

    public function setUsr_firstname($value) {
        $this->usr_firstname = fix_wrong_title_case($value);
    }
}
```

Then I do the following:

```php
$model = new User(['scenario' => User::SCENARIO_REGISTER]);
$model->usr_firstname = 'John';
```

But the setter method is never called! I have tried naming the method all kinds of things - eg. `setUsrFirstname` - but nothing works. How do I get this to work?

**UPDATE**

Figured out it doesn't work for any ActiveRecord attribute, with or without an underscore in the attribute name.

Comment: So are you saying that with method `public function setUsrFirstname($value) { $this->usr_firstname = fix_wrong_title_case($value); }` and calling it like `$model->setUsrFirstname('John');` it doesn't work?

Comment: @Bizley No, I'm not calling the setter method directly - that is the whole point with Yii's data transformation. Any time the attribute `usr_firstname` is modified anywhere in the system, Yii should automatically invoke the setter method `setUsr_firstname` and run the value through that before setting it in the model/object.

Comment: This does not work in case of properties declared directly or Active Record attributes (no matter if it's with the underscore or not).

Comment: You should handle this with a validation rule

Comment: @Bizley It is an ActiveRecord attribute but why won't it work with that? And what do I do instead?

Comment: @TheStoryCoder I was about to ask for the code you claimed is working but since you edited the comment you probably know now. The reason is [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L301) - AR's magic `__set` method doesn't allow it. You can use [FilterValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#filter) to get the same thing during validation or override models `afterFind()` and/or `beforeSave()` methods with that attribute.

Comment: @Bizley I see. Too bad there isn't a way to do it before the model is saved... But I guess you could call `$model->validate(); $model->clearErrors();` to actually achieve it! If you want to write your comment as an answer I can accept it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setter method is not called in case of properties declared directly or Active Record attributes (no matter if it's with the underscore or not).

Active Record's magic `__set` method assigns value directly to the mapped attribute.

You can achieve something similar with new virtual attribute:

```
public function setUsrFirstname($value)
{
    $this->usr_firstname = doSomethingWith($value);
}

public function getUsrFirstname()
{
    return $this->usr_firstname;
}
```

So now you can use it like:

```
$this->usrFirstname = 'John';
echo $this->usrFirstname;
```

If you want to modify the attribute in the life cycle of AR you can:

- use [FilterValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#filter) to change it during validation,
- override model's `afterFind()` method to change it after DB fetch,
- override model's `beforeSave()` method to change it before saving to DB,
- prepare behavior that can do all the things above,
- prepare method to be called directly that will change it (you can use the first setter method for this; no need to call `validate()` and `clearErrors()`).